# An error occurred While checking trigger in flow screen,there is any resolution solution?

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow, after-trigger

[image]

Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: TransactionAct: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Class.TimelineEventController.timelineTrigger: line 182, column 1 External entry point Trigger.TransactionAct: line 16, column 1. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.

This my Code of

1. TransactionAct trigger:

   ```
       trigger TransactionAct on Loan_Transaction__c (after insert) {
       List<Timeline_Event__c> timelineList=new List<Timeline_Event__c>();
       TimelineEventController tobj=new TimelineEventController();
       ITimelineEventController timeAssignCtrl=new TimelineEventController();


       for( Loan_Transaction__c trans :Trigger.New){
       Timeline_Event__c tEvent=new Timeline_Event__c();
              string rtype='', subtitle='';

       if( Trigger.isInsert){


           if(trans.Type__c=='Disbursal'){
               subtitle=rtype+'Disbursal of';
         tevent=(Timeline_Event__c)timeAssignCtrl.timelineTrigger(trans,'TransactionAct Disbursal', subtitle,'', '','insert','trans');
            timelineList.add(tEvent);
           }    
           else if(trans.Type__c=='Payment'){
                subtitle=rtype+'Payment of';
    tevent=(Timeline_Event__c)timeAssignCtrl.timelineTrigger(trans ,'TransactionAct Payment',subtitle,'','','insert','trans');
               timelineList.add(tEvent);
           }

              }

         }
    tobj.createMany(timelineList);  
    }
   ```
2. TimelineEventController

   ```
           public class TimelineEventController implements IController, ITimelineEventController{
           @AuraEnabled
         public static List<SObject> getAll(){
                   return [SELECT
                     Name,Event_Date__c,Event_Type__c,Related_Id__c,Related_Object_Name__c,
                     Related_User_Id__c,Title__c,Description__c,Object_Id__c
                FROM Timeline_Event__c
                ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
                LIMIT 1000];                         
    }

       @AuraEnabled
        public static List<SObject> getAll(SObject value){
        return getAll(value,null);
    }

    public static List<SObject> getAll(SObject value,String autoNumber){
        Timeline_Event__c param = (Timeline_Event__c)value;
        String queryString = 'Select Name,Event_Date__c,Event_Type__c,Related_Id__c,Object_Id__c,'+
                              'Related_User_Id__c,Title__c,Subtitle__c,Description__c,Related_Object_Name__c'+
                        ' from Timeline_Event__c where';

        if(!string.isBlank(autoNumber)){
            queryString += ' Name = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(autoNumber) +  '\' AND';
        }
        if(param.Event_Date__c  != Null){
            queryString += ' Event_Date__c = '+ param.Event_Date__c +' AND';
        }
        if (!string.isBlank(param.Object_Id__c)) {
            queryString += ' Object_Id__c = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(param.Object_Id__c) + '\' AND';
        }

        if (!string.isBlank(param.Event_Type__c)) {
            queryString += ' Event_Type__c = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(param.Event_Type__c) + '\' AND';
        }

        if (!string.isBlank(param.Related_Id__c)) {
            queryString += ' Related_Id__c = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(param.Related_Id__c) + '\' AND';
        }

        if (!string.isBlank(param.Related_User_Id__c)) {
            queryString += ' Related_User_Id__c = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(param.Related_User_Id__c) + '\' AND';
        }

        if (!string.isBlank(param.Title__c)) {
            queryString += ' Title__c = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(param.Title__c) + '\'';
        }

        queryString = queryString.removeEnd(' AND');
        List<SObject> timeline=Database.query(queryString);
        return timeline;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static SObject getById(Id id){
        SObject entity = [SELECT
                            Name,Event_Date__c,Event_Type__c,Related_Id__c,Object_Id__c,
                             Related_User_Id__c,Title__c,Subtitle__c,Description__c, Related_Object_Name__c
                        FROM Timeline_Event__c
                        WHERE Id=:id];
        return entity; 
    }


    public Id create(SObject value) {
        Timeline_Event__c entity = (Timeline_Event__c)value;
        insert entity;
        return entity.Id;
    }

    public Boolean createMany(List<SObject> values) {
        List<Timeline_Event__c> entities = (List<Timeline_Event__c>)values;
        insert entities;
        return true;
    }

    public Boolean edit(SObject value) {
        Timeline_Event__c entity = (Timeline_Event__c)value;
        update entity;
        return true;
    }

    public Boolean editMany(List<SObject> values) {
        List<Timeline_Event__c> entities = (List<Timeline_Event__c>)values;
        update entities;
        return true;
    }

    public Boolean remove(Id id) {
        Timeline_Event__c entity = [SELECT Id FROM Timeline_Event__c WHERE Id=:id];
        delete entity; 
        return true;
    }

   @AuraEnabled
   public static List<SObject> getAllByLimit(Id id,Integer l){
       List<sObject> entities=[SELECT
                     Name,Event_Date__c,Event_Type__c,Related_Id__c,Object_Id__c,
                     Related_User_Id__c,Title__c,Subtitle__c,Description__c, Related_Object_Name__c
                FROM Timeline_Event__c
                WHERE Object_Id__c = :id
                ORDER BY Id DESC
                LIMIT :l]; 
       return entities;
   }

   public static SObject timelineTrigger(SObject obj,string tit,string sub,string des,string etype,string dml,string objName){
       Timeline_Event__c tobj=new Timeline_Event__c();
       SObject sObj;
       string objId='';
       if(objName=='application'){
           sObj=(Application__c)obj;   
           tobj.Related_Object_Name__c='Application__c';
           if(sObj.get('Account__c')!=null){
               tobj.Object_Id__c=(string)sObj.get('Account__c');
           }
           else{
               tobj.Object_Id__c=(string)sObj.get('Contact__c');
           }
       }
       else if(objName=='bank'){
           sObj=(Bank_Account__c)obj;
           tobj.Related_Object_Name__c='Bank_Account__c';
           if(sObj.get('Account__c')!=null){
               tobj.Object_Id__c=(string)sObj.get('Account__c');
           }
           else{
               tobj.Object_Id__c=(string)sObj.get('Client__c');
           }
       }
       else if(objName=='benefit'){
           sObj=(Benefit__c)obj;
           tobj.Related_Object_Name__c='Benefit__c';
           tobj.Object_Id__c=(string)sObj.get('Contact__c');
       }
       else if(objName=='contact'){
           sObj=(Contact)obj;
           tobj.Related_Object_Name__c='Contact';
           tobj.Object_Id__c=(string)sObj.get('Id');
       }
       else if(objName=='account'){
           sObj=(Account)obj;
           tobj.Related_Object_Name__c='Account';
           tobj.Object_Id__c=(string)sObj.get('Id');
       }
       else if(objName=='employment'){
           sObj=(Employment__c)obj;
           tobj.Related_Object_Name__c='Employment__c';
           tobj.Object_Id__c=(string)sObj.get('Contact__c');
       }
       else if(objName=='expense'){
           sObj=(Expense__c)obj;
           tobj.Related_Object_Name__c='Expense__c';
           tobj.Object_Id__c=(string)sObj.get('Contact__c');
       }
       else if(objName=='loan'){
           sObj=(Loan__c)obj;
           tobj.Related_Object_Name__c='Loan__c';
           if(sObj.get('Account__c')!=null){
               tobj.Object_Id__c=(string)sObj.get('Account__c');
           }
           else{
               tobj.Object_Id__c=(string)sObj.get('Contact__c');
           }
       }
       else if(objName=='transaction'){
          sObj=(Loan_Transaction__c)obj;
           tobj.Related_Object_Name__c='Loan_Transaction__c';

           if(sObj.get('Account__c')!=null){
         tobj.Object_Id__c= Schema.Sobjecttype.Loan__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Account__c').getRecordTypeId();
           }
           else{
              tobj.Object_Id__c= Schema.Sobjecttype.Loan__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Contact__c').getRecordTypeId(); 
           }

       }
       if(objName=='employment'){
            tobj.Event_Date__c=(DateTime)sObj.get('Start_Date__c');
       }
       else if(dml=='insert'){
           tobj.Event_Date__c=(DateTime)sObj.get('CreatedDate');
       }
       else{
           tobj.Event_Date__c=(DateTime)sObj.get('LastModifiedDate');
       }

       tobj.Subtitle__c=sub;
       tobj.Event_Type__c=etype;
       tobj.Title__c=tit;
       tobj.Related_Id__c=(Id)sObj.get('Id');
       tobj.Related_User_Id__c=(Id)sObj.get('LastModifiedById');
       tobj.Description__c=des;

       return tobj;
   }

   public static string aLink(Id lid,String word){
       return '<a href="/lightning/r/'+ lid +'/view">'+ word +'</a>';
   }

   @AuraEnabled
   public static string getIdPrefix(){
       Schema.DescribeSObjectResult k=Application__c.sObjectType.getDescribe();
       return k.getKeyPrefix();
   }

   @AuraEnabled
   public static string getUserName(Id id){
       UserController userObj=new UserController();
       User userDetails= (User)userObj.getById(id); 
       return userDetails.Name;
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 2):

In your trigger, if you see the error message it comes from line 16,

```
tevent=(Timeline_Event__c)timeAssignCtrl.timelineTrigger(trans,'TransactionAct Disbursal', subtitle,'', '','insert','trans');
```

Here, you're passing the sobjectName as 'trans', now in your apex method that gets invoked, there's no condition that accepts 'trans', instead you're looking for

```
else if(objName=='transaction'){ on line 166
```

You need to change this to look for 'trans' on line 166

```
else if(objName=='trans'){
```

I hope this helps.

Best,
Vishal

Comment: It showing same error in another line this 167 lineTimelineEventController `sObj=(Loan_Transaction__c)obj;`  error: **Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: TransactionAct: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type Loan_Transaction__c to Loan__c Class.TimelineEventController.timelineTrigger: line 167, column 1 External entry point Trigger.TransactionAct: line 16, column 1. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide** @Vishal